# Pandas shifted value calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to create a new column, containing values calculated from shifted value in other columns.

As you see the code below, first I created a time series data.

'price' is randomly generated time series data, and momentum is average momentum value of recent 12 periods.

I'd like to add a new columns, containing data with average 'n' momentum value, in which 'n' correspond to the value of df['shift'], not with fixed 12 value in the momentum function, but with the value in the 'shift' column.

How can I do this?

(In the example below, momentum was calculated with fixed 12)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(low=0.8, high=1.3, size=100).cumprod(),columns = ['price'])
df['shift'] =  np.random.randint(5, size=100)+3
df

def momentum(x):
    init = 0
    for i in range(1, 13):
        init = x.price / x.price.shift(i) + init
    return init / 12

df['momentum'] = momentum(df)

       price  shift  momentum
0   1.069857      3       NaN
1   0.986563      7       NaN
2   0.809052      5       NaN
3   0.991204      3       NaN
4   0.846159      6       NaN
5   0.717344      4       NaN
6   0.599436      3       NaN
7   0.596711      7       NaN
8   0.543450      4       NaN
9   0.511640      3       NaN
10  0.496865      3       NaN
11  0.460142      4       NaN
12  0.435862      4  0.657192
13  0.410519      4  0.665493
14  0.368428      5  0.640927
15  0.335583      7  0.625128
16  0.313470      7  0.635423
17  0.321265      4  0.704990
18  0.319503      7  0.746885
19  0.365991      4  0.900135
20  0.300793      4  0.766266
21  0.274449      6  0.733104
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my approach

```
def momentum(shift,price,array,index):
    if shift > index:
        return 0
    else:
        init = 0
        for i in range(1,int(shift)+1):
            init += price / array[int(index)-i]
        return init



df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(low=0.8, high=1.3, size=100).cumprod(),columns = ['price'])
df['shift'] = np.random.randint(5, size=100)+3
df['Index'] = df.index
series = df['price'].tolist()


df['momentum'] = df.apply(lambda row: momentum(row['shift'],row['price'],series,row['Index']),axis=1)
print df
```